# Is there any way to export NStableView data as PDF with Table View Column titles

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am working on cocoa Mac app where I have to implement Export NStableView Data as PDF. I am able to export TableView data as PDF but there have one issue PDF not showing TableView Column as header in PDF.I have attached both Tableview and PDF screen shots along with code which I am using to achieve above feature.

```
NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()

NSGraphicsContext.current!.compositingOperation = NSCompositingOperation.clear
            
NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()

let pdfData = reporttableview.dataWithPDF(inside:reporttableview.bounds)

let pdfNSData = NSData.init(data: pdfData)

var path = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.downloadsDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as [String]).first ??  ""
path.append("testFile.pdf")

pdfNSData.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)
```

1. TableView data Listing

[TableView data Listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za0ej.png)

2. Exported PDF

[Exported PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEpIT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The header view is outside the table view. Create an offscreen table view in a scroll view, enlarge the scroll view so the entire table view is visible and create a PDF of the scroll view.